# Orchard CMS. How correct display shape in zone?

Tags: orchardcms, orchard-modules

I have a module Orchard.MyModule. In module is shape Orchard.Web\Modules\Orchard.MyModule\Views\Parts\Header.cshtml

in Header.cshtml is code

```
...
Model.ContentItem.Id
...
```

If in layout.cshtml

```
Func<dynamic, dynamic> Zone = x => Display(x);
@if(Model.Header != null)
{
  @Zone(Model.Header)
}
```

Always yellow page of death and Model.ContentItem = null.

If in layout.cshtml delete it code, then will be situations:
1) In admin panel set in Header zone widget Header.cshtml.  --- NOT DISPLAY
2) In admin panel in Header zone empty, Header.cshtml in BeforeContent zone. ---  Header shape(Header.cshtml) will be displayed 
3) All zones empty. --- NOT DISPLAY

Shape Header.cshtml redefines Header zone? How insert in Header zone Header.cshtml and display it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I assume `Parts/Header.cshtml` is being displayed by a driver.

```
protected override DriverResult Display(MyPart part, string displayType, dynamic shapeHelper) {
    return ContentShape("Parts_Header", () => shapeHelper.Parts_Header();
}
```

Something like this?

Then you can take the shape type (ie the first argument in ContentShape: "Parts_Header") and send this part to the main layout zone in your modules `Placement.info` like this:

```
<Place Parts_Header="/Header:1" />
```

The import part being the **/** before Header, which tells Orchard this shape should be displayed in the main layout zone